# jQuery append gif while ajax call not working in Chrome, Firefox. Works in IE(no animation though)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {  

        var startDate = $("#startdate").val();
        var endDate = $("#enddate").val();
        var selected = $("#selected").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/json/chart",
            data: {
                selected:selected, 
                startDate:startDate, 
                endDate:endDate
            },
            success: function(data) {  

                $("#pkgLineDiv").empty().html("");                  

                $.each(data, function(index) {                         
                    $('#pkgLineDiv').prepend('<img id="'+ index+'" src="/public/images/ajax-loader.gif" /><br />');
                    $('#'+index).attr('src', 'chart/'+ data[index].pkgLineId +'/'+ data[index].wrapSpecId +'/'+ data[index].startDate +'/'+ data[index].endDate);                   
                });                           
            }

        });
        return false;           
    });
});
```

This is my code. I'm doing an ajax submit and getting some json data back. I'm then passing this data into a chart url. This chart url is a function that generates an image in the back end. The problem is this could be a long process. A simple ajax loading image doesn't work because the ajax call is quick (gets a quick json array). It's what happens after the ajax call that take a while. What I'm trying to do is get an image to show where the image will be. I can't have a place holder because I don't know how many images are going to be created.

This code will work in IE 8. The animation will not play but at least the image shows up where the final image will be. In Chrome and Firefox (my main testing environments) the image will not show at all. Is there something I am missing here? Thanks.

## EDIT

:

```
      $("#pkgLineDiv").empty().html("");  //Empty all contents of the div to push new chart images       
                $.blockUI();
                $.each(data, function(index) {    

                    var chartUrl = 'chart/'+ data[index].pkgLineId +'/'+ data[index].wrapSpecId +'/'+ data[index].startDate +'/'+ data[index].endDate;  //Build chart URL
                    $('#pkgLineDiv').prepend(''+ data[index].description +'<div><img id="'+ index +'" src="/public/images/ajax-loader4.gif" /></div');


                    $.get(chartUrl, function() {                           
                        $('#'+index).attr('src', chartUrl);  

                        if (index == data.length - 1) {
                            $.unblockUI();   
                        }                       
                    });      
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done this before so I can't say for sure, but perhaps try to initially set the img srcs to the loader.gif then make ajax requests to each of the chart/'+ data... (i.e. the chart images) then on success set the src to the chart image.  If the chart image's headers indicate the client can cache that URL, then I believe it should work the way you want.

I believe the issue is how different browsers handle the changing of img src.  If you don't change the src until you know the image has been rendered by the server and cached by the client, you should be good.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function() {  

        var startDate = $("#startdate").val();
        var endDate = $("#enddate").val();
        var selected = $("#selected").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/json/chart",
            data: {
                selected:selected, 
                startDate:startDate, 
                endDate:endDate
            },
            success: function(data) {  

                $("#pkgLineDiv").empty().html("");                  

                $.each(data, function(index) {                         
                    $('#pkgLineDiv').prepend('<img id="'+ index+'" src="/public/images/ajax-loader.gif" /><br />');

                    var chartUrl = 'chart/'+ data[index].pkgLineId +'/'+ data[index].wrapSpecId +'/'+ data[index].startDate +'/'+ data[index].endDate;

                    $.get(chartUrl, function(data){ $('#'+index).attr('src', chartUrl); }); // get


                }); // each                           
            } // success

        }); // ajax
        return false;           
    }); // click
});  // ready
```

Comment: Make the ajax request to the URL of the chart, on success set the src of the image to the URL of the chart.  The browser should have cached the image locally, you can ensure that it does by adding the proper HTTP headers to the page that is generating the charts.  If, for example, a call to "chart?a=10&b=5" always produces the same chart, you should already be ensuring that the image is cached for some time on the client, so take advantage of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This solved the image problem perfectly.  I've been messing around with trying to block interaction on the page while the chart is loading.  You don't have any ideas for that do you.  If I put the blocking at the start and end of the $.get it doesn't work.  It blocks and immediately unblocks.  Not a big deal I guess.  Just wondering.  Thanks.

Comment: Drew, hmmm -- start blocking before the $.each... line.  Then you need to keep in mind the ajax calls are asynchronous, so they are sent out to the server, then the "function(data)" piece gets executed on the "callback" when the response comes back from the server.  What you want to stop blocking only after *all of the $.get* calls have "called back".  So in the callback put a check in there and if they've all completed loading and called back, then unblock.  There are lots of ways to implement it I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help again.  I've implemented what you have specified.  The unblock command is always called a few seconds before the image is actually loaded.  Take a look at my code in the original post if you can.  I wonder if there is a way to check if the tag is the loader image or the actual chart.  Then unblock on that.  Thanks.

Comment: That is a good idea (checking the src), but you need to check all of them from 0 to (index -1) in a loop because the last one by index isn't necessarily going to the last chart generated by the server and "called back".

Comment: Check Simon's comment below, the "async: false" option does appear a better fit for your needs, overall.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like the BlockUI plugin from http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

You can manually set the blocking and unblocking of the screen.

Comment: The problem with this is the Ajax request is short.  It's a simple JSON request.  I take that JSON data and then build the URL of the chart.  When I pass this data to the URL the chart is then generated in the background.  I have no idea how long this will take so I can't use anything like this.  Unless someone can point me in the direction of how to use an ajax request to get an image back and then put that on the screen.

Comment: You should use the async: false option on the Ajax call so it waits until the call is finished prior to clearing the screen

Comment: Well there is two ajax calls.  One is the main call that gets the JSON data.  That one is fast.  The second is an ajax call to the charts.  This is the one that takes the longest.  I'll have to change it to a regular call because I don't think you can set the async to false on shorthand ajax methods.

Either way I can get the blockui to disable when it needs to disable.  The async: false on the chart ajax call just freezes the page.  I'm wanting to show the blocking ui if I can.

Comment: Either way I can get the blockui to disable when it needs to disable.  The async: false on the chart ajax call just freezes the page.  And I've also noticed that the page unfreezes a few seconds before the image is shown, just like with the blockingui(unblocks a few seconds before the chart shows) in my above code.  I'm wanting to show the blocking ui if I can the whole time.